# What is the difference between Uni1, Uni2, and Uni3 terminal font codesets?

Tags: terminal, fonts

I'd like to change my terminal font to any of:

```
/usr/share/consolefonts/Uni1-Fixed15.psf.gz
/usr/share/consolefonts/Uni2-Fixed15.psf.gz
/usr/share/consolefonts/Uni3-Fixed15.psf.gz
```

What is the difference between Uni1, Uni2, and Uni3 codesets? How am I to choose among them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are part of the [`console-setup`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/console-setup) package in Debian, and reading the sources for those would show you that the answer is in [Chapter 2 - bdf2psf](http://download.vikis.lt/baltix/baltix-ubuntu-packages/edgy/ubiquity-installer/old/d-i/source/console-setup/doc/console-setup.html/ch3.html) of The Hackers Guide for console-setup:

> **`Uni1`** (512 glyphs)
>
> Supports most of the Latin languages, the Slavic Cyrillic languages, Hebrew and barely Arabic.
>
> **`Uni2`** (512 glyphs)
>
> Supports most of the Latin languages, the Slavic Cyrillic languages and Greek.
>
> **`Uni3`** (512 glyphs)
>
> Supports most of the Latin and Cyrillic languages.

The 512 is a limitation of the Linux console.

There also appears to be some mapping (multiple characters to single glyphs), because the number of Unicode values in each source-file does not match the 512-glyph limit:

```
$ wc -l Uni1.512 Uni2.512 Uni3.512
     502 Uni1.512
    1870 Uni2.512
    1854 Uni3.512
    4226 total
```